# jQuery displayed text of value

Tags: jquery

I have a color picker module that opens in a popup and when you choose a color and close the popup, there is a small square under the popup selector that displays the chosen image. I would like to display the text of the chosen image (currently as alt text of the chosen image). Any ideas?

Currently I have it like this:

```
<img id="selected-color" width="30" alt="Brez" title="Brez" src="http://defaultimage.jpg">
```

and

```
$("#selected-color").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
$("#selected-color").attr("title",$(this).attr("title"));
$("#selected-color").attr("alt",$(this).attr("alt"));
```

Now how can I display the alt text under the ?

Comment: What's `$(this)` at this point? And is `#selected-color` the color-picker, or the element you want to show the text-color in?

Comment: selectable option image with jquery [iconselect](http://bug7a.github.io/iconselect.js/)

Comment: `$( "#selected-color" ).attr({
  alt: $(this).attr("alt"),
  title: $(this).attr("title"),
  src: $(this).attr("src")
});`